# Bitwise addition of opposite signs

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, twos-complement, bitwise-xor

```
int main(){
        int a = 10, b = -2;
        printf("\n %d \n",a^b);
        return 0;
}
```

This program outputs -12. I could not understand how. Please explain.

```
0111 1110 -> 2's complement of -2
0000 1010 -> 10
---------
0111 0100
```

This no seems to be greater than -12 and is +ve. But how did I get the o/p as -12 ?

Comment: Hint: what is 2's complement of 12 ?

Comment: -2 is actualy 11111...10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the two's complement of a negative integer, first find the binary representation of its magnitude. Then flip all its bits, i.e., apply the bitwise `NOT` operator `!`. Then add `1` to it. Therefore, we have

```
2       -->  0000 0000 0000 0010
~2      -->  1111 1111 1111 1101  // flip all the bits
~2 + 1  -->  1111 1111 1111 1110  // add 1
```

Therefore, the binary representation of `-2` in two's complement is

```
1111 1111 1111 1110
```

Now, assuming the size of `int` is 4, the representation of `a` and `b` in two's complement is -

```
a -->        0000 0000 0000 1010  --> 10
b -->        1111 1111 1111 1110  --> -2
a^b -->      1111 1111 1111 0100  --> -12
```

The operator `^` is the bitwise `XOR`, or exclusive `OR` operator. If operates on the corresponding bits of `a` and `b` and evaluates to `1` only when the bits are not both `0` or both `1`, else it evaluate to `0`.

Comment: 1111 1111 1111 0100 - Is this no -12 ?. what happened to the bits set before it. If MSB is set with 1, we consider it as a minus no. What happens to the bits set from 5th bit till the 15th bit.

Comment: @Angus that's sign extension. `10100` is -12 and adding the sign bit to the left of the number doesn't change its value

Comment: @Angus Here's the rule. If the MSB is `1`, then the number is negative. To get its modulus, flip all the bits and add 1.

Comment: @Roma-MT Yes, `(!(a^b))+1` would give the magnitude since `a^b` is negative.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: I couldnt still get it. can you please explain in detail.

Comment: @ajay add it to your answer ! it will be helpful for future users !

Comment: @Ajay: Thanks. I could get why -12.

Comment: @ajay the bitwise not should be `~`, not `!`. So that's `~2 + 1`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, right! I somehow mixed it. fixed now. Thanks much :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems legit!

```
1111 1110   (-2)
xor
0000 1010   (10)
=
1111 0100   (-12)
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the bitwise XOR, not power

```
a = 10 = 0000 1010
b = -2 = 1111 1110
──────────────────
a^b    = 1111 0100 = -12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(int) -2 = 0xfffffffe

(int) 10 = 0x0000000a                                  

0xfffffffe ^ 0x0000000a = fffffff4 = (int) -12
```

Comment: When answering using code fragment please describe what it does and how it fixes the problems.